# tensorflow.keras model with multiple inputs with different shapes (Error)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Heyho, I want to build a Keras Model with multiple inputs which have different shapes.
This is my model:

```
input_shape_board = (8,8,12)
input_board = tf.keras.Input(shape = input_shape_board, name = "board_input")
        
input_shape_legal = (1984)
input_legal = tf.keras.Input(shape = input_shape_legal, name = "legal_input")

a = layers.Dense(64)(input_board)
a = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(a)
a = layers.Dense(64)(a)
a = layers.Flatten()(a)
        
b = layers.Conv2D(64, 4, activation='relu')(input_board)
b = layers.MaxPooling2D((4,4))(b)
b = layers.Flatten()(b)
        
c = layers.Dense(200, activation='relu')(input_legal)
        
d = layers.Concatenate()([a,b,c])
        
d = layers.Dense(1984)(d)
outputs = layers.Activation('sigmoid')(d)   

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=(input_board, input_legal), outputs=outputs)
```

I later train with (kind of - with adapted values) the following:

```
board_array_onehot = np.ones((1,8,8,12))
tmp_arr_legal = np.ones((1984))
inputs = (board_array_onehot, tmp_arr_legal[0])

arr_predictions = models[active].predict(inputs)
```

I have made sure, that all my inputs are numpy arrays, but I now get the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'tuple'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.float64'>", "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

I have tried several different variations with this brackets and my input, but it still won't work. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: In this line `board_array_onehot = np.ones((1,8,8,12))`, Is the  dimensions are correct? because you trained with  `input_shape_board = (8,8,12)`.

Comment: and also `inputs = (board_array_onehot, tmp_arr_legal[0])` here you give all array instead of one array. Try `inputs = (board_array_onehot[0], tmp_arr_legal[0])`

Comment: yes thats true, I did add that one additional dimension earlier, when training with a network with only one input and it seemed to need it back then.. I removed it, and it gives the exact same error.

Comment: the other hint unfortunately didn't help either.. I get an error regarding wrong input dimensions if I change it to the "right" values

Comment: Try this `tmp_arr_legal = np.ones((1984,1))` this gives you an array instead of `numpy.float` this is what your error says.

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow with this model, I solved it with adding an additional dimension in front of the fed input.

so while I had defined:

```
input_shape_board = (8,8,12)
input_board = tf.keras.Input(shape = input_shape_board, name = "board_input")

input_shape_legal = (1984)
input_legal = tf.keras.Input(shape = input_shape_legal, name = "legal_input")
```

I actually had to feed:

```
board_array_onehot = np.ones((1,8,8,12))
tmp_arr_legal = np.ones((1,1984))
inputs = (board_array_onehot, tmp_arr_legal[0])

arr_predictions = models[active].predict(inputs)
```

but I don't understand why?